# Add guitext in to gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am working on multiplayer collaboration in unity3d using smartfox server2x . In this there are 2 scripts 
a)game manager.cs is drag in to game object  and  b)timer.js script  is drag into guitext . How can i add this  guitext into game object? When i am trying to do this iam getting an error like

> "There is no 'GUIText' attached to the "Game" game object, but a
>   script is trying to access it.
>
> You probably need to add a GUIText to the game object "Game". Or your
>   script needs to check if the component is attached before using it."

This is ma script

```js
#pragma strict
public var timeLeft:float = 10.0f;
public var IsTiming : boolean;

//public bool IsTiming = false;
   public function Start () {
   //IsTiming = false;

 }
 function test1(vr1:boolean) 
 {
 IsTiming=true;
 Debug.Log("enter33333333333"+IsTiming);
//gamemanager = this.GetComponent("GameManager");

}
function OnGUI() 
  {
 Debug.Log("enter2222222222"+IsTiming);
if(GUI.Button(Rect(0, 70, 150, 25), 'counter')) 
{

IsTiming = true;

}
if(IsTiming)
    {
    Debug.Log("enterzzzzzzzzzz");
        timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (timeLeft <= 0.0f)

        {

            guiText.text = "You ran out of time";
            guiText.text = "Time is over";


        }  
        else

        {

            guiText.text = "Time left = " + timeLeft + " seconds";

        }

       }
  }
```

How can i add this script in to game object "Game".

Answer (score 1):

The error will be happening because your game object does not have a [GUIText](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIText.html) component; you need to add one first.

To add a GUIText component, you could write `gameObject.AddComponent(GUIText)` within your `Start` function.

Or, you could add a GUIText component via the Unity editor menus by going **Component > Add...**, then type in **GUIText**.

Also, writing `guiText` in your script is shorthand for writing `GetComponent(GUIText)`!

Comment: but i want to script in gameobject.

Comment: Okay, so in your `Start` function, write `gameObject.AddComponent(GUIText);`, then you'll be able to manipulate the `guiText` variable.

Comment: @Chris GuiText is deprecated in version 5